# bind символьных клавиш в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, события

Какое событие отвечает за нажатие именно символьных клавиш `[0-9a-zA-Z...]`?
Я хочу отфильтровывать такие события,как `Shift,Esc,Enter` и.т.д.

Можно сделать так:

```
def check(a):
    k=a.keysym
    if a.char and k not in ('Escape','Tab','Return','BackSpace'): #Все остальные,не указанные в скобках,несимвольные события клавиатуры выдают пустую строку и не проходят через первое условие
        print(e.char)
```

но это не очень надёжно и довольно громоздко. Есть ли конкретное событие?

Answer (score 0):

```
root.bind('a',your_func)
```

С цифрами также.

Comment: это-то понятно,но мне же нужно забиндовать все символы,не делать же мне цикл for на 40000 итераций всевозможных символов,должно существовать простое событие нажатия любого символа,но не дополнительных клавиш вроде Esc,Enter и т.д.